# How to search longer content more than regular in when using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I maintain a legacy system (which uses PHP and MySQL). I encounter a problem when search content from database. For example, I have a query to search:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment_content LIKE '%"$term"%'";
```

I use UTF-8, MySQL with InnoDB type, When the length of $term is 8067 (Japanese) characters (number also like text characters), there are no problem. When the length of $term is 8068 characters, cannot search, this is my problem.

- What is the maximum length when full text search use PHP and MySQL?
- How to resolve my problem?

Your help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What kind of error do you get?  What does it say?  Can you show the code where you actually make the database request (using mysql/mysqli/pdo)?

Comment: that is not a "full text search" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Err... something like this in actual code.

1. Check the length of $term len() function

   ```
   len($term) if $term is >8067 then do stuff
   ```
2. Iterate over a number of times 8067 characters fit into $term rounded up

   ```
   $charachterincrement=8067
   $searchtermcount = roundup(len($term)/8067,0)

   $searchterm = "comment_content LIKE" & left($term,$charachterincrement)
   ```

   $i=1

   ```
   do while $i <= $searchtermcount 
       $i = $i+1
       $charachterincrement=$charachterincrement+8067
   ```
3. Create a new `$searchterm` that will house your 'like' statement.
4. For each iteration add this to your `$searchterm`

   ```
   $searchterm = $searchterm & " AND comment_content  LIKE '%" & mid($term, $charachterincrement, 8067) & "'%"
   ```
5. close the loop

   ```
   loop
   ```
6. Close the if

   ```
   end if

   $query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE $searchterm;
   ```

This will create a SQL statement that will require all parts of your initial $term in your search query. It will not take order into account though, it will just check to see if each 8067 string exists in the post.